# How to add databaseURL to firebase/flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase

I got the following error when trying to run a cloud function::

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL, config is actually{"projectId":"mynotes-b58d2","storageBucket":"mynotes-b58d2.appspot.com","locationId":"us-east4"}
 If you are unit testing, please set process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG
```

I was told I need to add the following::

```
  "databaseURL":"https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
```

but I dont know where to add it, or what my baseURL is or where to find it

any help is welcomed

update::

i found where to add the info
firebase_options.dart>DefaultFirebaseOptions.

now i need to kmwo what my base url should be

update. i think i got it but i wanna tripple check with somone

I added in two places::

```
  static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'XXXX,
    appId: 'AAAA',
    messagingSenderId: '333333',
    projectId: 'mynotes-flutter-project',
    storageBucket: 'mynotes-flutter-project.appspot.com',
    databaseURL: "https://mynotes-b58d2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",
  );

  static const FirebaseOptions ios = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'XXXX,
    appId: 'AAAA',
    messagingSenderId: '333333',
    projectId: 'mynotes-flutter-project',
    storageBucket: 'mynotes-flutter-project.appspot.com',
    iosClientId:
        '877208178211-pkk6a4dfdsmh1tfm4ffhdss9lmmjl0mc.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosBundleId: 'se.pixolity.mynotes',
    databaseURL: "https://mynotes-b58d2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",
  );
```

is this correct?

update: its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

I recommend letting the `flutterfire` CLI generate `firebase_options.dart` for you, instead of trying to update it manually.

If the file doesn't contain a database URL, that's because you hadn't initialized the database in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/) when you ran `flutterfire`. After creating the database in the console, run `flutterfire` again to update the `firebase_options.dart`.